# Calling function from setTimeout() method

Tags: javascript, typescript, settimeout

Maybe a lot of you will find this question trivial, but after 3 days of searching without any answer i found the answer by myself and maybe someone in the future will need this title above while searching google..

I must understand Why A works and B does not?
why i can access my `this.MarkContents_Input()` function only as a delegate?

A.

```
refreshInputStatistics(): void {
        this.updateprocessing();
        setTimeout(() =>
            this.MarkContents_Input(this.vc.returnEditor(staticEditorDirective.textAreaEnum.LeftTextArea))
            ,50);
    }
```

B.

```
refreshInputStatistics(): void {
        this.updateprocessing();
        setTimeout(
            this.MarkContents_Input(this.vc.returnEditor(staticEditorDirective.textAreaEnum.LeftTextArea))
            ,50);
    }
```

I am very new to front end web development, maybe i am missing something(?)

**EDIT:**  my question was marked as duplicate, yes i agree, now i see its duplicated, but search keywords here can help others in the future (as mentioned above, unfortunately 3 days of search did not lead my to the first question, could have saved me a lot of headache...
)

Comment: Do you get an error in your browser console with B?
I think that ot is due to the mapping of this in Typescript

Comment: @NielsNet yes, using B. `this.MarkContents_Input()` is undefined, also visual studio IDE shows design time error.

Comment: Then the problem is due to the fact that this is not mapped to the source of your refresh method if you dont use a delegate...

Comment: is your refresh method in a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because how `this` works in Javascript and how fat arrow functions `() => {}` bind the `this` context. It can be very confusing to newcomers to Javascript. It is kind of a trap, but on the other hand it makes Javascript powerfull (you can use `somefunction.call(somethingWhatReplacesThis, whateverArguments)`

the A option is basically equivalent to something like this. I hope it make this more clear.

```
refreshInputStatistics(): void {
        this.updateprocessing();
        var that = this; // store context for usage in setTimeout
        setTimeout(            that.MarkContents_Input(that.vc.returnEditor(staticEditorDirective.textAreaEnum.LeftTextArea))
            ,50);
    }
```

**Deeper explanation**

The setTimeout() and other callback functions are evaluated in global context, where the `this` keyword points to the global object (usually `window`, but that depends on the environment in which the function is executed (Browser, NodeJs, Webworker...)
So in order to make it work, you need to capture the context to a variable.
The fat arrow function does it for you automatically, and transpiles to something similar to the example above.

**Useful links**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

[How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)